# Any tips on backwards compatible Adaptive text sizes (iphone6/5/5s etc)

Tags: ios, iphone, adaptive-design, adaptive-ui

working on updating UI for new phones. Naturally, i have a couple of text fields that appear smaller on iphone6/6 plus.

Since i need my app to work back to IOS5, i can't use auto layout or the new adaptive text field stuff. I have looked around a bit but there seems not to be much on the topic.

I really don't want to resort to setting textfield sizes with if(IPHONE6){...}, so if anyone has any better ideas, i'm all ears!

Comment: Why in the world do you support iOS5? There's your answer.

Comment: I don't think there's an alternative solution to `if (IPHONE6) { ... }`. I agree with Leo, drop iOS 5 support and move to AutoLayout.

Comment: I know and see your point. However for {insert reason here} we shall support ios5 a little while longer. :) Question - would autolayout also fix the font size issue?? I thought that the new features in ios8 was needed for that. Thanks for input.